# Finding the kth smallest element in an array using recursion?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void moveToKthSmallest(int a[], int size, int k); 


int main() {

int theArray[17] = {42, 5, 412, 56, 14, 98, 488, 4882, 24, 4, 9, 67, 9424, 2, 1, 3, 5};
int num;

cout << "Move to the kth smallest number in the array (size of 17): " << endl;
cin >> num;
moveToKthSmallest(theArray, 17, num);


return 0;
}

void moveToKthSmallest(int a[], int size, int k) {
int pivot = size / 2;
int pivotValue = a[pivot];
int index1 = 0, index2 = 0;
int s1[size], s2[size]; //not sure about this


for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (a[i] < pivotValue) {
        s1[index1] = a[i];
        index1++;
    }
    else {
        s2[index2] = a[i];
        index2++; 
    }
}

int s1Size = index1; //problem?
int s2Size = index2; //problem?

if (s1Size == k - 1) {
    cout << pivotValue;
}

else if (s1Size > (k - 1)) {
    moveToKthSmallest(s1, s1Size, k);
}

else if (s1Size < (k - 1)) {
    moveToKthSmallest(s2, s2Size, k - (s1Size - 1));
}
}
```

I ask the user to input a number (greater than or equal to 0 or less than or equal to 17) and the program should output the kth smallest number in the already generated array.

The above is my attempt but it crashes whenever I run it. I think it has something to do with the declaration of the arrays s1 and s2 in the function and possibly the size values generated from index1 and index2. I've tried using vectors and dynamic arrays but I keep getting error messages in my compiler such as "error: cannot convert 'std::vector**' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void moveToKthSmallest" ... to be quite honest, I'm not quite sure what that means.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score -1):

The first point of order is that this is tagged C++ and not C. Therefore, instead of an `int a[]` and an `int size`, you should be using a straightforward `std::vector<int>`.

Now, with that out of the way, in your example, you're iterating over the entire array each time you recurse.

The second point of order, I don't understand why recursion is even needed here. The answer can be found with a single iteration over your array.

The most simplest way of doing that is to use a second array, let's say `std::vector<int> smallest`, then iterate over your `std::vector<int> a` just once.

When iterating over each element:

- if `smallest.size()` is already `k`, and the current value is larger than the last value in `smallest`, then proceed to the next value in `a`, otherwise remove the last value in `smallest`.
- at this point, `smallest.size()` is always less than `k`, therefore add the current value in `a` to the `smallest` in a manner that keeps the `smallest` array in sorted order.

At the end of the iteration, the last value in the `smallest` vector is the kth smallest value in your original vector.

If you would like to know the position of the kth smallest value, this is just a minor modification to the above algorithm, by tracking the position in the `smallest` vector, rather than the value.

This seems to be a much simpler, straightforward solution, then a complicated recursion-based approach with a confusing pivoting operation. Also, your pivoting example requires the original array to be modified, while my approach does not, and can be used with a `const std::vector<int>`, even.

P.S. It's not really necessary to keep `smallest` in sorted order. With a slight modification to the algorithm, `smallest` can remain unsorted. The homework assignment here is to adjust this algorithm to not require `smallest` to remain in sorted order.